# MIKROE-55 - LCD Datasheet

Tags: led, resistors, lcd

I'm a bit confused by the datasheet of a LCD (MIKROE-55).
It says supply voltage is 3.5V (TYP), which results in as Supply current of 16mA.

At first I understood this as: "connect K to GND and A to 3.5V and I'm done :)"

But below that table is a graphic showing 2 Resistors (1 on seems to be on boards, 1 external).

So my question: How to connect that backlight? If a Resistor is required, how to calculate its Value.

Full Datasheet can be found here:
[Datasheet](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/272/-364177.pdf)

[image: Datasheet page]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you (both!)

- have a 3.5V supply that is sufficently accurate
- can live with a LED current that can be any value between 13 mand 20 mA

then you can ideed apply 3.5V directly.

For a higher voltage you must add an external resistor. For instance, for 5V you need a regsistor of 1.5V/16mA `= 100 Ohm.